# Unable to update app: Failed to compile JSP Files

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp, compiler-errors

I'm trying to deploy an App for the first time on the App Engine and i'm getting an error saying "Unable to update app: Failed to compile JSP Files".  Anyone have any ideas how can i fix this.  I've set up eclipse to point to JDK1.6.0_17 in Windows/Preferences/Java/Installed JREs. My JAVA_HOME is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17". I've also edited the appcfg.cmd file in the "appengine-java-sdk-1.4.2\bin" folder to look like the following:

`@"%JAVA_HOME%"\bin\java -cp "%~dp0\..\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar" com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg %*`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Read a bit back in the logs. Are there any feasible JSP compilation errors prior this general appengine error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have both a JRE and a JDK and Eclipse uses the JRE when deploying which is the problem. It should use the JDK. Uninstall the JRE (using the Programs and Features control panel). Make sure your path is set to the JDK. If you don't see it add it in the PATH variable. It should be something like: c:\Program Files\java\jdk\bin. Adapt it based on your own config.