# CSS not rendering on Chrome for Gwt application deployed in AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I wonder why my GWT application deployed in Appengine (Appspot)                                                                       won't render properly with Google Chrome while being rendered properly with Firefox. I have tried both Chrome and Firefox under development mode and there is not problem for the two browsers.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What version of SDK are you using?

Comment: If you have no answer when asking "what could be causing this", try to provide more elements (for example a link to the application).

Comment: @PeterKnego Appengine version 1.6.1, is it because of the version?

Comment: Could it be because I have this on the gwt.xml file: <collapse-all-properties /><collapse-all-properties />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known CSS deployment bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/zqa5x7utULo) in SDK 1.6.1. The solution is to update your SDK to the latest version.

Comment: I updated to SDK 1.6.5, the app works in localhost, however I cannot upload to Appengine cloud, having this error: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622726/unable-to-update-app-failed-to-compile-jsp-files

Answer (score 0):

I added this on the html / jsp being loaded:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="...">
```

Answer (score 0):

GWT creates two different cache files for two different browsers. this code is different in development mode and product mode.

you can check which file is loaded with developer tools in your browser.

is something like 6AF04C348A1F695F02971B5F417097D4.cache.html in one browser and a different *.cache.html (z.B. AA66E93E26DE37E8FA7F748457739037.cache.html) in the other browser.

you can see all compiled cache Files in your WAR/[modulename]/ folder

if you want to analyse this files you should compile it without obfuscation:

GWT Compile with outputstyle "detailed"