# Google App Engine - Failed to compile the generated JSP java files

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My project works fine locally, but when trying to deploy it to the GAE servers, I get the following error message:

```
Unable to update app: Failed to compile the generated JSP java files.
```

This happened mainly when I switched from Java 7 to Java 6, since apparently GAE doesn't support that yet. I am using GAE 1.7.4, is this a known problem? What is wrong with the project? Is it syntax within the JSPs? They used to compile before I starting using GAE 1.7.4, but I don't know the exact cause of when this started.

Comment: See if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622726/unable-to-update-app-failed-to-compile-jsp-files) helps, possible duplicate.

Comment: The link above tells you to use the JDK, not JRE. However, I have the same problem as the original poster, and I am definitely using the JDK. After the error message, there are lines telling me that the JSP's are built:
`1-feb-2013 17:24:55 org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
INFO: Built File: \session.jsp`
No other messages appear. At the end GAE tells me to look in the log-file, which only has a `com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException`, but no useful information.

Comment: There is a (recent) [appengine issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8725) for exactly this problem.

Comment: So it is specifically a 1.7.4 problem? Like enver, I have the JDK being used and not the JRE.

Comment: I am not sure if the problem is specific for 1.7.4. It could be z problem in the appengine at Google's side. But since I see very few references to this problem, I suspect that it is a problem in my code and yours. We just happen to run into it at the same time.

Comment: I tried reverting my code to a previous version that has deployed correctly. It does not deploy anymore. It looks like this is a problem in either 1.7.4. or the appengine itself. There is no activity on the issue about this, so I guess if you experience this problem you are in trouble.

Comment: try to run and test all jsp files their must be error in any of the file. I got solved this problem this way

Comment: I too have faced the same issue , But it does not worked from any of the solution mentioned above in my case , even after jsp validation also in eclipse . I have to modify the code from 2days previous backup code to the current change manually and then it deployed sucessfully in gae server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been having the same problem and was convinced that there was a GAE problem. However, now I realize that I had changed the name of a .java file referenced by a couple of my .jsp files and the file name had not gotten changed in the .jsp. After I fixed the file name in the .jsp deployment worked normally again. Arrgh.

I think before GAE started compiling the JSP files, JSP files with errors would deploy successfully. Also, when running locally, the JSP are apparently not compiled until they are accessed, so unless all the JSP files are tested locally, you may not know of the error. But if you try to deploy, the JSP compilation fails and the deploy is aborted. Unfortunately, there is no sensible error message to suggest where the problem was found.

Comment: This ended up being it, a colleague of mine had screwed up some declarations in a JSP. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This was probably my problem as well. I cleaned up a bunch of unused jsp files, and now deploying works as usual. It would still be helpful if the eclipse plugin gave a clear error message.

Comment: For me too I had called some variables in the jsp that I haven't declared in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

I try to recompile java files on eclipse again and check the errors.
I think this is better way to check it.

This is my blog for the detail.
http://nurinamu.tumblr.com/post/62384368766/how-to-detect-the-jsp-compile-error-when-deploy-to

Comment: I have no idea why the above answer is marked correct, it just there is no easy way to find the problem, this guy's blog post works fantastic and gives you the exact location of the problem, thanks @Nurinamu!

Comment: @Shaun: This answer appeared after the older answer had been marked. The blogpost from Nurinamu is indeed a better answer.

Comment: In my case, the staging directory was at `/tmp/appcfg459335648151314286.tmp`, while the generetad files were in `/tmp/1435342307356-0`. I have to import the latter into eclipse to got the error messages and solve them. So it seems that the right folder is the one ending with `-0`, Also, if you have difficulties to find these files, they all ends with `_jsp.java`. So under Linux you can find them using `find <directory> -type f -name "*_jsp.java"`, where <directory> is the parent directory of the staging directory (in my case `/tmp`). Then, you can link to  the directory containing these files.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue.  I had changed the method signature of a method that was called by a JSP I didn't normally go to.  So when running locally everything worked fine because I never went to the problematic JSP.

The way to resolve this is to run locally and go to every single JSP in your project.  Eventually I got to a JSP that gave me a full stack trace locally in my browser window.  When I fixed the error in that JSP I was again able to deploy to app engine production.

It would be better if GAE was able to report which JSP is failing, but this technique will work.

Answer (score 2):

I was running in the same issue. Yes the error your get in Eclipse and in the log is really unhelpful, but wanted to share that deploying to the local dev server instead gave a very helpful error message, e.g. in my case:

---

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 286 in the jsp file: /dashboard.jsp

Duplicate local variable datastore

```
283:   </head>
284:   <body onload="initialize()">
285:     <%
286:     DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
287: 
288:     UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
289:     User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
```

---

Saved a big headache.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "deploying to the local dev server". I could run my application locally without problems. Can you expand a little bit on that?
The problem with my application disappeared when I cleaned out some old unused jsp files. They probably contained references to something that did not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

nurinamu's answer is ok but it didn't work for me because my project was too complex and I wasn't able to resolve the errors I got from linking the source folder generated in the appengine staging area. However I did manage to fix my problem!

This method is a bit of a pain but in a worst case scenario: **move the JSPs out of your project and do a test deploy until you narrow down and find which JSP is causing the issue.**

This was really the only way I could figure out what was causing the problem.

**UPDATE**

For me the error was a rogue import that wasn't supported by appengine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a JSP include you must make sure that the JSP file, which you include in other files, has all the proper imports, even if everything seems to work well in the test environment.

For example, if you have a file called `inc.jsp` and in other files you include it like so:

```
<%@include file="inc.jsp" %>
```

Then inside `inc.jsp`you must make sure all the proper imports are there even if the compiler hasn't explicitly complained about it.

An easy way to find the errors in an include JSP is to try and open it in a browser when running the development server. You'll see the JSP errors that the compiler didn't tell you about there.

This is one reason I found for the error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make Sure that all jsp files run on local so for that you can
try to `run and/or test all jsp files on your local`. Their must be error in any of the jsp file.

I got solved this problem in this way.

I only have error in one jsp file but it show the same error for all jsp files so don't worry about all files.