# Jsp Compilation error using Google App Engine Plugin for eclipse

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I am trying to learn the usage of Google App Engine using Java by trying to run the example in their website. I am using Eclipse Juno in Linux as my IDE. It hosts on my local machine successfully, but while trying to deploy it to the App Engine, it fails to compile the JSP files.
**SignGuestbookServlet.java**

```
    package com.guest.book;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

public class SignGuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SignGuestbookServlet.class.getName());

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws IOException {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
        String guestbookName=req.getParameter("guestbookName")==null?"default":req.getParameter("guestbookName");
        Key guestbookKey=KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);
        String content = req.getParameter("content");
        Date date=new Date();
        Entity greeting = new Entity("Greeting",guestbookKey);
        greeting.setProperty("user", user);
        greeting.setProperty("content", content);
        greeting.setProperty("date", date);

        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        datastore.put(greeting);
        resp.sendRedirect("/guestbook.jsp?guestbookName="+guestbookName);
   }
}
```

**guestbook.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.User" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory" %><html>
    <head>
    <title>Guestbook</title>
  </head>

  <body>

<%
    String guestbookName= request.getParameter("guestbookName");
    if(guestbookName==null)
    {
        guestbookName="default";
    }
    pageContext.setAttribute("guestbookName", guestbookName);
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
      pageContext.setAttribute("user", user);
%>
<p>Hello, <%= user.getNickname() %>! (You can
<a href="<%= userService.createLogoutURL(request.getRequestURI()) %>">sign out</a>.)</p>
<%
    } else {
%>
<p>Hello!
<a href="<%= userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI()) %>">Sign in</a>
to include your name with greetings you post.</p><br>
<%
    }
%>
<%
        DatastoreService datastore=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
        Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook",guestbookName);
        Query query= new Query("Greeting",guestbookKey).addSort("date",Query.SortDirection.DESCENDING);
        List<Entity> greetings = datastore.prepare(query).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5));
        if(greetings.isEmpty())
        {%>
        <p> Guestbook <%= guestbookName %> has no messages.</p>
        <%
            }
        else
        {
        %>
        <p>Messages in Guestbook <%= guestbookName %>.</p><br>
        <%
            for(Entity greeting : greetings)
            {
                if(greeting.getProperty("user")==null){
        %>
            <p>An anonymous person wrote:</p>
        <%
            }
        else
        {
        %>
        <p><b><%= greeting.getProperty("user") %></b> wrote: </p>
        <% 
        }
        %>
        <blockquote><%= greeting.getProperty("content") %></blockquote>
        <%
            }
        }
        %>  
<form action="/sign" title="Dash" method="post">
    <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Post Greeting" /></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="guestbookName" value="<%= guestbookName %>"/>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Error Log**

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:238)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:214)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1181)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC$LocalCompiler.<clinit>(LocalJspC.java:53)
    ... 7 more
Error while executing: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -classpath /home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/impl/appengine-api-labs.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/impl/google_sql.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/impl/appengine-local-runtime.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/impl/appengine-api.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/impl/appengine-api-stubs.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/shared/jsp/repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/shared/jsp-api.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/shared/appengine-local-runtime-shared.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/shared/servlet-api.jar:/home/abdul/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7.1/lib/shared/el-api.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/classes:/tmp/1366711497850-0:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jasper-jdt-6.0.29.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-labs.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jakarta-standard-1.1.2.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jta-1.1.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.7.1.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-ant-1.7.1.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-tomcat-juli-6.0.29.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jakarta-jstl-1.1.2.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jasper-6.0.29.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-jasper-el-6.0.29.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/repackaged-appengine-ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar:/tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/lib/jsr107cache-1.1.jar: -Dcom.google.apphosting.runtime.use_java6=false com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC -uriroot /tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp -p org.apache.jsp -l -v -webinc /tmp/appcfg7995795059214651808.tmp/WEB-INF/generated_web.xml -d /tmp/1366711497850-0 -javaEncoding UTF-8
```

Comment: Where is the error ? Side note - Please avoid using scriptlets. JSTL and EL can do whatever scriptlets can and they are easier to maintain.

Comment: Added Log. And what do you mean by JSTL and EL? Sorry i'm a beginner.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638655/java-eclipse-google-app-engine-failed-to-compile-the-generated-jsp-java-files